# Firebase retrieve and assign data from parent and children to class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following firebase class. Patients and users(doctor, hospital stuff) is a many to many relation.
[image]

Patients Class

```
public class Patients {
    public String name;
    public String surname;
    public ArrayList<String> users;
}
```

And this is the way I iterated through the data **without** the `users` (field of table `patients` **NOT** the table) field on firebase database on `patients` table.

```
database.child("patients").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot patient : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Patients p = patient.getValue(Patients.class);
            //use p object
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        patientsList.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Of course this doesn't work with the current format of `patients` table because the children of `users` (field of table  `patients` **NOT** the table, needs another loop) and I get that. The thing that I don't get is how can I associate the `Patients` class with `patients` table when I have to do another loop. I can't figure a way for `Patients p = patient.getValue(Patients.class)` to work with another field that needs iteration.

My goal is the object `p` of `Patients` class to contain for example
`name = Mark`, `surname = Marks` , `users[] = [y92pZ4rynpUFSOm3MrzQncimu153,...]`. I don't how the pojo should be structured and what's the proper way to iterate the children so users `ArrayList` will contain all the `users` field for each patient and using something like `Patients p = patient.getValue(Patients.class)`

Comment: Shortly, what do you want to have in your output?

Comment: @AlexMamo The `Patients` object to be associated with `patients` table. The code on last part where I iterate through the `patients` table works without `users` field.

Comment: There are no tables when it comes to Firebase. Firebase is a NoSQL database. You did not understand my question. What do you want to be printed? Give me an example containing values from your database.

Comment: I don't want anything to be printed,and if you are referring to the list view, it's irrelevant for my question. I want to get the values from firebase and use them. I edited and removed a list I was using because it's irrelevant to the question and don't want to focus on there.

Comment: I've updated the question. I don't know if that works for you as an example My goal is the object `p` of `Patients` class to contain for example
`name = Mark`, `surname = Marks` , `users[] = [y92pZ4rynpUFSOm3MrzQncimu153,...]` I don't how the pojo should be structured and what's the proper way to iterate the children so users `ArrayList` will contain all the `users` field for each patient.

Comment: Have you set all the getters and setters in your pojo class?

Comment: No, because I've seen that firebase needs public variables and I had some exceptions with getters and setters and when I removed them it worked. The thing is I don't know if this is even possible. Is `users` field an ArrayList or something else? How should I write those nested loops? I can do it by hand but this isn't OOP. I need to find a way to "automatically" assign those users to the patient class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the pojo class with public fields and witout the `no argument constructor` and the coresponding setters and getters is completely wrong! All your fileds need to be private and you need to access them only trough public setters and getters. Remember, that the no argument constructor is mandatory for Firebase. That's why you cannot map that node. Add them to your pojo class and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Alex, it's not that. Yes I changed the variables to private and added setters and getters. But my problem is the ArrayList. What type is it and how to iterate through the children. `Patients p = patient.getValue(Patients.class)` that should automatically assign `Patients` pojo with the firebase equivalent. But, this causes a `Failed to bounce to type` exception because `users` has children and needs another loop and the variable `ArrayList` from pojo isn't correct.

Comment: You need to understand that witout the **`no argument constructor`** Firebase won't work at all. It's perfect that you have added the public setters and getters. Another thing to remember is that in Firebase there are no tables. Firebase database is structured as pairs of key and values which means that every node in the database is a `Map`, so you don't need that ArrayList in your pojo at all. You can query your database let's say, for names, and add them into an ArrayList in the `onDataChange()` method and do what you want for it.

Comment: I see and I get it. So , there's no way the whole list to be instantly assigned to the pojo like simple entries like `name` and `surname`.

Comment: There is but is not a common practice. The flow is like this: attach a listener on the desired node -> get the names you want -> add them into an ArrayList -> do what you want with the ArrayList .

Comment: Even if it's not the answer that solved my problem, it probably saved me some frustrations. Thanks for sticking with me.